# Repeating background with cocos2d (Python)

Tags: python, cocos2d-iphone, pyglet

I am trying to write a (board) game with cocos2d in python. I want to have a nice grass texture as background, and it should repeat itself when the Window is resized.

Currently I loaded sprite and just drew it multiple times in a batch, depending on the window size. Problem that i am encountering is that when the window is resized i have to redraw the background every time but I think that this is not the way to go.

For the C++ API of cocos2d, there is something like GL_REPEAT, but I did not find such thing for the python API. Is there something I have been missing, or do you know an easier approach?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you find solution ?